# AJAX File upload on LIferay: unable to match parameters

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui

I'm trying to write a Liferay portlet that sends a file upload over AJAX to a JSONWS endpoint, but I keep getting the following errors in the logfile:

```
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-70][JSONWebServiceActionsManagerImpl:121] Request JSON web service action with path /document/upload-file and method POST for //document-portlet
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-70][JSONWebServiceActionsManagerImpl:455] Found 1 JSON web service actions with path /document-portlet/document/upload-file in for //document-portlet
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-70][JSONWebServiceActionsManagerImpl:501] Unable to match parameters to a JSON web service action with path /document-portlet/document/upload-file for //document-portlet
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-70][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:97] No JSON web service action associated with path /document/upload-file and method POST for //document-portlet
```

Following a couple of tutorials, my JSONWS implementation looks like this:

```
class DocumentServiceImpl extends DocumentServiceBaseImpl {

    @JSONWebService(method="POST")
    public String uploadFile(File content) {
         // ...
    }
}
```

And here's my client-side code:

```
<aui:form name="files" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <aui:input type="file" name="content" label="File" />
    <aui:button type="submit" name="btnUploadFile" value="Upload file" />
</aui:form>

<script>
AUI().use(
    'aui-io-request',
    function(A) {
        var btnUploadFile = A.one("#<portlet:namespace />btnUploadFile");

        btnUploadFile.on("click",
            function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var myForm = A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>files");
                var ajaxURL = "http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/document-portlet.document/upload-file";

                var configs = {
                    method : 'POST',
                    form : {
                        id : myForm,
                        upload : true
                    },
                    sync : true,
                    on : {
                        complete : function() {
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                };

                A.io.request(ajaxURL, configs);
            }
        )
    }
);
</script>
```

It looks to me like Liferay discovers the uploadFile method, but it can't match the signature of the request to the parameters of the method. How do I match parameters for a multipart/form-data request? Or am I going about this the wrong way?